# Python List of np arrays to array

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I'm trying to turn a list of 2d numpy arrays into a 2d numpy array.  For example,

```
dat_list = []
for i in range(10):
    dat_list.append(np.zeros([5, 10]))
```

What I would like to get out of this list is an array that is (50, 10).  However, when I try the following, I get a (10,5,10) array.

```
output = np.array(dat_list)
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

you want to stack them:

```
np.vstack(dat_list)
```

Comment: For list of arrays with different shapes, one should use: np.concatenate(list, axis=None)

Answer (score 3):

Above accepted answer is correct for 2D arrays as you requested. For 3D input arrays though, vstack() will give you a surprising outcome. For those, use stack(<list of 3D arrays>, 0).

Answer (score 1):

See https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.append.html
for details. You can use append, but will want to specify the axis on which to append.

```
dat_list.append(np.zeros([5, 10]),axis=0)
```