# How to convert an array to np.array?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, cluster-analysis, k-means

I want to use an array of centers in my k-means algorithm.
This is my array

```
[[-5.158116189420494, -6.135869490272887, -7.112943870919113, -4.719408271488777, -8.652736411771516, -5.115898856180194, -9.444466710512513, -6.721183141827832, -8.187939363193856, -4.866007421496122, -4.498541424902005, -6.05955187591462], [2.4503788682948797, 4.136767712097715, 3.800113452319174, 1.7263996510061559, 6.204316437195861, 3.199580908124732, 5.4996984541468565, 3.504064521222991, 1.7285485126344595, 1.9327954130937557, 4.491668242286317, 2.4442089524354818], [8.91661735243092, 8.19164570547311, 7.28941813144091, 11.01087393409493, 9.666237508380636, 7.689372230181427, 10.796081659572991, 10.587480247869069, 12.490792204659163, 9.146059052365413, 4.077223320288767, 8.748918676524138], [-5.007715234440542, -5.201881954076602, -2.990066071487654, -6.50605352762039, -6.097032315522047, -4.81206434114537, -5.453803052692122, -5.968516137674577, -4.087403530804171, -4.9456413319696315, -3.748488710268994, -3.8879845624490703]]
```

And this is the way I am defining k-means to use it

```
km = KMeans(n_clusters=4, init=cluster_centers, max_iter=30)
km.fit(Xnorm)
km.predict(Xnorm)
y_kmeans = km.predict(Xnorm)
```

I get this error

```
ValueError: init should be either 'k-means++', 'random', a ndarray or a callable, got '[[-5.158116189420494, -6.135869490272887, -7.112943870919113, -4.719408271488777, -8.652736411771516, -5.115898856180194, -9.444466710512513, -6.721183141827832, -8.187939363193856, -4.866007421496122, -4.498541424902005, -6.05955187591462], [2.4503788682948797, 4.136767712097715, 3.800113452319174, 1.7263996510061559, 6.204316437195861, 3.199580908124732, 5.4996984541468565, 3.504064521222991, 1.7285485126344595, 1.9327954130937557, 4.491668242286317, 2.4442089524354818], [8.91661735243092, 8.19164570547311, 7.28941813144091, 11.01087393409493, 9.666237508380636, 7.689372230181427, 10.796081659572991, 10.587480247869069, 12.490792204659163, 9.146059052365413, 4.077223320288767, 8.748918676524138], [-5.007715234440542, -5.201881954076602, -2.990066071487654, -6.50605352762039, -6.097032315522047, -4.81206434114537, -5.453803052692122, -5.968516137674577, -4.087403530804171, -4.9456413319696315, -3.748488710268994, -3.8879845624490703]]' instead.
```

From the message I'm reading I think I need to use a specific format for the array.
How can I make the convertion?

### Calculation of centers to be used

```
for i in range(0,100):
    X=dataML
    X = X[np.random.default_rng(seed=i).permutation(X.columns.values)]   
    #X = X.sample(frac=1).reset_index(drop=True)
    Xnorm=mms.fit_transform(X)         
    km=KMeans(n_clusters=4,n_init=10,max_iter=30,random_state=42)    
    y_kmeans=km.fit_predict(Xnorm)
    print('aqui')
    print(km.cluster_centers_)
    print('aqui 2')
    center_cluster01.append(km.cluster_centers_[0])
    center_cluster02.append(km.cluster_centers_[1])
    center_cluster03.append(km.cluster_centers_[2])
    center_cluster04.append(km.cluster_centers_[3])

meanC01=[]
for i in range(0,12):
    sum=0
    for j in range(0,100):        
        sum = sum + center_cluster01[j][i]            
    mean01 = sum/2
    meanC01.append(mean01)    

meanC02=[]
for i in range(0,12):
    sum=0
    for j in range(0,100):        
        sum = sum + center_cluster02[j][i]            
    mean02 = sum/2
    meanC02.append(mean02)    

meanC03=[]
for i in range(0,12):
    sum=0
    for j in range(0,100):        
        sum = sum + center_cluster03[j][i]            
    mean03 = sum/2
    meanC03.append(mean03)    

meanC04=[]
for i in range(0,12):
    sum=0
    for j in range(0,100):        
        sum = sum + center_cluster04[j][i]            
    mean04 = sum/2
    meanC04.append(mean04)
```

### Xnorm

```
Xnorm=mms.fit_transform(dataML)     
cluster_centers = [meanC01, meanC02, meanC03, meanC04]
km = KMeans(n_clusters=4, init=cluster_centers, max_iter=30)
km.fit(Xnorm)
km.predict(Xnorm)
y_kmeans = km.predict(Xnorm)
```

Comment: Please add your entire code/context to make it easier to answer. For example, showing where xnrom is initialized.

Comment: Here's the solution https://duckduckgo.com/?q=How+to+convert+an+array+to+np.array. If it doesn't work, edit your question to add what you have tried.

Comment: What are the outputs of `type(cluster_centers)` and `type(cluster_centers[0])`? If the first one is list and the second one is ndarray, then try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7200878/python-list-of-np-arrays-to-array

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the type of the first array you have? I'm seeing two sets of open brackets meaning it is multidimensional.

You might want to try flattening your array with numpy.ndarray.flatten().

I have had this issue with data not being passed in correctly because of dimension issues.

NumPy method description is [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html).

Comment: How I identify the type of the array?

Comment: Do print(type("name of array variable, in this case Xnorm")).

Comment: I just checked the documentation for Sklearn for the min-max-scaler fit_transform(). That is what it looks like you are using. So if you pass in your array into the numpy.ndarray.flatten() then your output should be that same array in one dimension.

Comment: I tried this way but I'm getting this error TypeError: descriptor 'flatten' for 'numpy.ndarray' objects doesn't apply to a 'list' object

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).